# Difference between +new Date() and 1*new Date()

Tags: javascript, compatibility

Google Analytics snippet uses `1*new Date()` to get a current timestamp, which seems to be one character longer than `+new Date()` which I expected to be used for this purpose, especially taking into account how thoroughly minified GA snippet is.

I had a look at ES5 spec and it looks like it should be the same: unary plus applies `ToNumber(GetValue(expr))` and returns it, multiplication applies 
`ToNumber(GetValue(expr))` to both sides and multiplies them.

Is there a JavaScript environment (maybe some old browser?) which produces different results for `+new Date()` and `1*new Date()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no semantic difference; both will return the same value in all JavaScript implementations.

As already identified, this is because the conversion happens with [ToNumber], which applies equally to the unary `+` and the infix `*` operands.

This assumes that the expression shown is complete as it's somewhat easy to 'accidentally' turn the unary `+` into an infix without a syntax error; and an infix `+` could undesirably result in string concatenation. These days I just use [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) (ES5, shimmed elsewhere) although I used to use `(+new Date)`.

Comment: It is. Full expression is `i[r].l=1*new Date()`